# System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement in .net 2.0

Tags: .net, asp.net, active-directory, directoryservices

Is there a:

> string name =
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName;

equivalence in .net 2.0 framework?
It uses the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement (ver 3.5) reference. I tried using that file on a .net 2.0 framework but to no avail.

Basically, I want to retrieve the full username (first name and last name) of the windows user (not Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_USER"] which only gives windows username)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The S.DS.AM namespace was introduced in .NET 3.5, and unfortunately, there's no 2.0 version of it.

You can query the current Windows user in an ASP.NET app using WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name - this gives you DOMAIN\UserName.

Then you'd have to do a user search in AD for that user with a DirectorySearcher object in order to find the corresponding DirectoryEntry. This will give you all the bits and pieces of that user.

```
    string currentUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

    string[] domainUserName = currentUser.Split('\\');
    string justUserName = domainUserName[1];

    DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://dc=(yourcompany),dc=com");

    DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot);

    ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn");
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenName");

    ds.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=person)(samAccountName={0}))", justUserName);

    SearchResult sr = ds.FindOne();

    if (sr != null)
    {
        string firstName = sr.Properties["givenName"][0].ToString();
        string lastName = sr.Properties["sn"][0].ToString();
    }
```

It's a bit complicated and involved in .NET 2.0 - can't change that :-(

Marc

Comment: I used Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_USER"] instead of WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name; tho.... but thanks... worked perfectly

Comment: be careful and make sure you dispose your directory entries. they tend to hang around forever and will jam once you run out of concurrent connections.

Comment: SillyMonkey: good point - this wasn't meant to be "production-grade" code either - just an illustration snippet.